# Fastest Javascript Framework for Phonegap

Tags: dojo, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, jqtouch

What is the lightest and fastest JavaScript framework for Phonegap?  JqTouch, JQuery-mobile, or Dojo-mobile?

Found this :

[https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/viewanalytics formkey=dEdOZVZRVUszSU8wVG4tZmtYNUdZdWc6MQ](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/viewanalytics?formkey=dEdOZVZRVUszSU8wVG4tZmtYNUdZdWc6MQ)

What do you think?

TQ.

Comment: why do you care about "lightest" if it's a phonegap app? The download footprint of the framework only matters if you're web-delivering your app

Comment: You can consider using Dojo Mobile and optimize it with the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode.  That will yield you the fastest and tightest set of code.

Comment: Dojo and Jquery seems to be a good choice and he licensing of both is friendly. XUI is not a bad choice too, because of it's small footprint.

Comment: @MichaelMullany i think it still matters, because it effects application package size, which, in some cases could be important.

Comment: All these frameworks compressed are 100kb +/- 50kb. It's not going to make a difference.

Comment: Even in local, a compressed framework will perform faster.

Comment: @kelvinfix Yes it does matter. The size of the the framework is not the only variable into how fast it will perform. It depends on the device, hardware acceleration capabilities, OS versions and how much local content you have in your app (yes it does matter). For example, jQM is known for being very heavy and slow. It is, even after all of the tricks I've learned and I've been working with it for about a year. It's also known for it's 300ms delay after you hit a button. JQM, however, is trying to be more web focused than for apps. I'd look into Zepto or iUi for something "light".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you'll have much success in getting objective answers with empirical evidence on this here. The PhoneGap community (although growing) is already a small subset of the mobile development community. I doubt many have start-to-finish implemented actual performance tests of these stacks and compared them:

```
Sencha-Touch -> PhoneGap -> Native iOS
Sencha-Touch -> PhoneGap -> Native Android
```

vs

```
jqTouch -> PhoneGap -> Native iOS
jqTouch -> PhoneGap -> Native Android
```

etc.

I'd try looking around for comparisons of the various JS frameworks themselves for any notable performance differences and start testing the PhoneGap implementations yourself to see if the PhoneGap wrap affects the performance of each beyond the margins of difference between the individual frameworks. Or perhaps you could consult directly with the PhoneGap documentation and/or dev team yourself as I imagine they've had to test on various platforms and frameworks already.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I know it is difficult to get an answer for such a objective question. What I hope is to get some feed back from user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the following](http://interfacethis.com/2011/adventures-in-html5-part-one/).  The author actually did spend the time re-doing his application in different JS frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I read it before I post this question. No answer too. Maybe all is still not yet mature. Sencha Touch seems to be the most matured.

Comment: Doesn't point to anything anymore. =/  Not even at the site's root. All 404s.